# An output of pseudo console (ConPTY) is eaten by Visual Studio debug output window

Tags: c#, .net, windows-console

I'm playing with a pseudo console in C# and I noticed strange behaviour inside a non-console application. The output from a pseudo console is eaten by the debugger (shown in VS output window) but it never arrives into the pipe inside the application. This is happening only for .NET Framework Windows Forms and WPF applications *(not for .net core)*. When the same application is running without a debugger or is started manually outside of VS, everything is fine and the output is correctly propagated by pseudo console output pipe.

I'm trying to have a simple text box application which is showing output from a pseudo console which is running command *"ping localhost"* in a separated process. The entire example is available at GitHub: https://github.com/akobr/ConPty.Sample and the problematic project is called *ConPty.Sample.Terminal.OldForms*.

My setup: Windows 10 Pro 1903 build 18362.59, Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.4.2, .NET Framework version 4.8.03752.

**[behaviour when the application is debugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XewT.png)**

**[a scenario without a debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTSg7.png)**

Does anybody know if this strange behaviour can be somehow disabled in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with this, but _specifically_ on .NET core 3.1.301 (with the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger vsdbg in VSCode), have you found out anything about this problem?

Comment: Nevermind, found the GitHub issue you opened with solution in the comments: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4380